# No compilation error but output error for the code (JCreator):

Tags: java, numbers, addition

#### Input

t (no of lines), next t lines contains space separated numbers.

#### Output

The output should return the sum of the numbers in each lines.

#### Problem

Have coded in JCreater, no compilation error! BUT the desired output is only obtained after uncommenting the commented lines, else the program is terminating abruptly and showing answers to be zero. And it is working only with `System.out.println` statement, any other bogus syntax is not getting the result!

#### Code

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        int t=0;
        BufferedReader StdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try
        {
            String line = StdIn.readLine();
            t = Integer.parseInt(line);
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        int m=0;
        int result[]= new int [t];
        for(int q=0;q<t;q++)
        {
        //  System.out.println("LOOP: "+q);
            m=fun_num();
            result[q]=m;
        }
        for(int q=0;q<t;q++)
            System.out.println(result[q]);
    }
    public static int fun_num()
    {
        int i=0,o=0,j=0,m=1,s=0,sum=0;
        String inp=null;
        BufferedReader StdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try
        {
            String line = StdIn.readLine();
            inp=line;
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }
        String inp2=" ";
        j=inp.length();
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            if (inp.charAt(i)== inp2.charAt(0))
                m++;
        }
        int num_in_order[]= new int [m];
        int num=0;
        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
        {
            if (inp.charAt(i)== inp2.charAt(0))
            {
                num_in_order[s]=num;
                s++;
                num=0;
            }
            else
            {
                o=((int)(inp.charAt(i))-48);
                num=(num*10)+o;
            }
        }
        num_in_order[s]=num;
        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
            sum=sum+num_in_order[i];
        return (sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look at wrapping System.in in a Scanner, it will make your life easier and your code will be easier to read.

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? Please clarify, give some example input and what you would expect the output to be.

Comment: Using a BufferedReader is fine, but it would make more sense to share one reader to read in the input, rather than attempt to make multiple

Comment: suppose the input:
2
1 2
25 6
Output:
3
31

Answer (score 0):

I think the very first reader you create (StdIn), is buffering all the input, before the readers in `fun_num()` get a chance to look at it. Try passing StdIn as a parameter to your "fun_num" function instead of creating it every time.